# Setting up the english transaction emails

Tags: email, language

So I started my Webstore in greece. Now I want to sell products in UK . So I already installed my language package and the default transaction  emails got replace by the greek one. How do I get the english ones back and actually send them, when my customer picks english as shop language? (At the moment he will still get the greek emails)

I'm using Magento 1.9 + and rwd theme. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to your `System > Configuration > General` and set your default `Locale Option` to Greece.

Then, select **Current Configuration Scope:** to your **UK** store from left upper part and then go to `General` again and this time set your `Locale Option` to `English (United Kingdom)`.

**IMP**

You should have a folder called **en_GB** in `app/locale` and there you should have your transactional/translation files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found the translation files, but how do I add them to my transaction emails in Magento Backend?

Comment: If you have your en_GB folder in place and have selected English (UK) in `Locale option` from Current confg scope then it should start working.

Comment: It doesn't work - the files won't show up :/

Comment: Files wont show up where?

Comment: transaction emails are still the same

Comment: You will have to choose "locale" in transactional email too. So basically if you want to edit them from admin panel, then need to create new one loading from UK locale.

Comment: Oh wow - now I see it!. Thank you for saving me a lot of time!